# what is the correct way of describing big theta?

Tags: algorithm

Regarding these codes:

code1:

```
arr[1] = 1;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
  if(arr[i]==1)
    break;
```

code2:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
  if(arr[i]==1)
    break;
```

code3:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
  for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
    //O(1) statement
```

code1 has big theta of 1 because search is always satisfied in first iteration (constant time).

code2 in best case has big theta of 1 and in worst case has big theta of n, without saying "worst case" sentence would saying "code2 has a big theta of n" be correct ? or is it invalid to describe the big theta of code which has multiple scenarios associated with it (best case, worst case, etc..) and we must describe its big theta in terms of a specific scenario ?

code3 has big theta of n^2, and its inner loop has a big theta of i which ranges from 1 to n, is it correct to say that the inner loop has a big theta of n even though it actually ranges from 1 to n ?

Comment: What does "car has 30mph" mean? You can guess what the person who wrote it might mean, but you'd just be guessing. It could mean the max speed, it could mean the car always moves at that speed, it could mean the car is currently moving at that speed. Same for "code has a big theta of n". It might mean "in the worst case, the code performs Theta(n) operations" or it might mean "in the best case, the code performs Theta(n) operations" or it might mean "over a uniformly random set of inputs of length n, the average number of operations the code performs is Theta(n)".

Answer (score 0):

1) correct

2) it is often not usful to talk about best case. With many algorithms you can be lucky, but if this happens only seldom, it is not relevant. It is more useful to talk about average case and worst case. Both are Theta(n) here. (Some assumptions have to be made about the numbers in the array. Compare also to case 1))

3) The O(1) statement will be executed approximately n * n/2 times, therefore Theta(n * n) is correct. The inner loop will run on average n/2 times.